How to call GetCurrentLocation() in C# (Android/Maui)
Background:
I have a foregroundservice that gets the current GPS location every n seconds using "RequestLocationUpdates". Works as expected, unless phone is in powersave mode, and screensaver active. Trying to use AlarmManager to work around this, and app is woken up by the alarm. I then check the GPSDateTime stamp, and if old, I know phone has been sleeping and I need to get the GPS location. If not so old, then I create a new alarm. Rinse and repeat.
I tried implementing Xamarin.Essentials and Microsoft.Maui.XYZ, but they dont return a location (could be due to the phones powersave mode)
I would like to use LocationManager.GetCurrentLocation() that's available from API 30 to get a single GPS location. GPS is already "warmed" up and has a fix before phone goes to sleep (foregroundservice), so I dont need to spend time waiting for this part to complete.
Problem: The last parameter, IConsumer. How todo that part in C#?!?!?
PS: Not working:
{
var location = _locationManager?.GetCurrentLocation(
  LocationManager.GpsProvider,
  null,
  ContextCompat.GetMainExecutor(Application.Context),
  locationCallback);
}

private Consumer<Microsoft.Maui.Devices.Sensors.Location> locationCallback = new MyLocationCallback();

private class MyLocationCallback : Java.Lang.Object, Java.Util.Functions.IConsumer
{
    public void Accept(Java.Lang.Object p0)
    {
        Microsoft.Maui.Devices.Sensors.Location location =
          (Microsoft.Maui.Devices.Sensors.Location)p0;
          if (location != null)
          {
              //Do something with location
          }
   }
}

See
How to use LocationManager#getCurrentLocation in Android for Java example
https://medium.com/@priyavrat.acharya01/using-new-on-demand-location-update-api-introduced-in-android-11-69c65b3787aa for Kotlin example
I found some Kotlin to C# or Java to C# websites, but none of them produced working code, or anything close enough for me to guess how to do the last bit.
Suggestions?

Did you get any error?

yeah, plenty, as the snippet above does not compile (at all). Lots of red lines "everywhere". Its the IConsumer part I can't figure out how todo in C# (locationCallback)

Can you add the error messages to the question? And what is Consumer<T>?

@shingo: think you need to re-read the question. None of it compiles as its just a bunch of C#'ish syntax. Its not one error; the whole IConsumer is not correctly written. Try this from MS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/java.util.functions.iconsumer?view=net-android-34.0 I can't make it work.

But it seems like you already have a class that implements IConsumer, can't you just pass new MyLocationCallback() as the last parameter?

No, if I somehow get something that compiles, it does not produce anything that can be used. Can you re-write the class to make it write out the lat/lng data?
The example code I have above, is junk produced by Java and Kotlin to C# online translators, not working code.

Refer to the doc of MAUI: Geolocation?

That documentation does not help on how to create the IConsumer part of the function call. Maybe you @JianweiSun-MSFT could provide such an example for everyone?
Also, I wasn't able to get the Maui location stuff to return a location when in powersave and locked screen.

Well, I got it. BTW, you can see this case: Continuous location update in .NET MAUI.

Hi and thanks for your effort, but there are two problems:. The comment by Álvaro-garcía says its does not work when in background. I have the same issue with my foreground service, (Android suspends it when in powersave mode and screenlock is enabled), which is why I want to use the GetCurrentLocation() API call, which is what the question asks, how to structure the IConsumer parameter. As an MSFT person, I have faith that you will figure this out for all of us!
